# New folder doesn't appear in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, osx-mountain-lion

Many times I have the following problem. I create a new folder, but it doesn't appear in the Finder. Right now I have this problem with a folder created in Eclipse. After a while it appears, but I cannot tell when. I can see the folder in the terminal. A similar problem happens when I rename a folder or file. Then I have to move out of the parent folder, open another folder, go back, and most of the time it's there. (Finally the new folder appeared after creating another folder in the finder itself.)

I'm using 10.8 Mountain Lion now, but this is not a problem of this release. I have this problem for several years now.

Maybe I'm the only one with this problem? Is there a way to get this working normally?

Comment: Is this problem with all files or only on network files?

Comment: Does this happen when you create a new folder from the Finder as well, or only from within Eclipse (or any other apps)?  If you are having this problem creating the new folder on a remote share, how are you accessing it (LAN vs WAN, afp vs smb, etc)?  What other apps are you running, including any background-type apps such as anti-virus?  Are you using any sort of disk encryption, such as FileVault or SafeGuard?

Comment: @da4: this happens on the local disk. It's not only Eclipse. I download something in Firefox, it doesn't appear in the Finder for a while. Or I see the filename of the downloaded file with a tmp file next to it. The filename has filesize 0, and cannot be opened.

Comment: However... I can create a new folder with the Finder, and after removing that folder, the other file appears. So that's my trick for now, but not a real solution.

Comment: I'm not using Filevault of Safeguard. I use Crashplan, no AV, Dropbox and the usual stuff.

Comment: This happens off and on for me too. I'm on 10.7.5. I notice it most often when I'm in Sublime Text 2 and I create a file or folder, and its view does not refresh. I finally observed it in Finder as well and realized it wasn't ST2. To reproduce, I can have a Finder window open, touch a new file via Terminal, and it doesn't appear in the Finder window. One day things are fine, reboot the MacBook, and out of nowhere the issue is back.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to remedy this today by:

1) Repairing Disk Permissions
2) Rebooting

I was then able to see new folders & files created within Sublime Text 2 as I created them.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of old, but I figure it might help someone. 
I've had the same issue for a while now, something to do with disk permissions and whatnot, especially when I copy folders from a remote pc. Anyways, I found that if you right click in the folder where your folder is supposed to be and choose 'Get Info', it pops right up!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Searching the Internet a bit I found a similar discussion, where the solution of the problem was simply to adjust the grid size in the finder.

See if you can solve your problem like this too: [Newly saved files not appearing on desktop](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=256631).

Comment: Thanks. The solutions mentioned there do not solve my problem.